# Switch to tab under "more" section not working on iOS - .net Maui

Tags: c#, navigation, tabs, maui

In my Maui application I want to switch tabs programatically. This works fine when the tabs get shown in the Tabbar. As soon as they are under the "more" section however, setting the current item on the tabbar only shows the "more" selection and not the item itself.
In my example, when I navigate to tab 1:

[image]

On the other hand, if I navigate to tab 8:

[image]

Example navigation code:

```cs
        public void SwitchToLastTab()
        {
            await Current.GoToAsync($"///{nameof(TabPage)}");
        }
```

AppShell.xaml:

```xml
<Shell
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MauiTestApplication"
    Shell.FlyoutBehavior="Disabled">

    <TabBar x:Name="MainTabBar"/>

</Shell>
```

In the AppShell.xaml.cs file I only register the routes and create the tabs for the tabbar.

Please note, that this was tested on an Iphone 14 Plus simulator (iOS 16.4).
It seems to work fine on android (Pixel 5 - API 33) and Windows Machine.

Comment: What kind of navigation is this? Very strange. What I usually have in code is something like: Shell.Current.GoToAsync("///tab8"). Triple slash is for changing the navigation stack, to the stack of the other tab.

Comment: The problem also seems to occur when using triple slashes.
 (`await Current.GoToAsync($"///{nameof(TabPage)}");`)

PS: I admit that this is a strange way of navigation, in the other parts of my application I obviously use Shell.Current.GoToAsync(). Its just that I'm not sure how to handle tab navigation.

Comment: Switching between tabs is done with triple slash "///", it swaps the navigation stack. May I see your Shell xaml? Also, do you have this problem on Android/Win, or just IOS?

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I was wondering how to do that correctly :)
I updated my question above with all the information requested, I hope this helps.

Comment: It is not "correctly", it is one way of doing it. If everything is working on Android/Win, it must be a bug on IOS. I do not want to discourage you to search for solution but: https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/15103. I am sorry.

Comment: If you are interested what I do, at my 5th tab, I have a CollectionView, holding image icon + text. (Looks like menu). And I have TapGesture on each item, navigating me to another page. Sometimes with "//" clearing the stack, sometimes "/". Downside - I do not have separate navigation stacks for each page. Upside - it works. So you can try implementing it, if you want.

Comment: Looks like there is nothing much we can do here. I'm not sure if Your solution will suffice for what I'm trying to do but I'll give it a try.
Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 0):

From the Apple docs [The More navigation controller](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitabbarcontroller#1653016) and [Tab bars](https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/tab-bars), the `more section` of the Tab bar is designed by Apple. You should use the minimum number of tabs required to help people navigate your
app. Each additional tab increases the complexity of your app, making
it harder for people to locate information.

> The tab bar has limited space for displaying your custom items. If you
> add six or more custom view controllers to a tab bar controller, the
> tab bar controller displays only the first four items plus the
> standard More item on the tab bar. Tapping the More item brings up a
> standard interface for selecting the remaining items.

However, you can still use [Absolute routes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/shell/navigation#absolute-routes) to navigate to the tab item under more section.

Here's the code for your reference:

```
<TabBar x:Name="MainTabBar" Route="MainTabBar"> 

       <!-- Omitted for brevity>

        <Tab   Title="Welcome"
                Icon="dotnet_bot.png">
            <ShellContent Route="WelcomePage" 
                      ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:WelcomePage}" />
        </Tab>

</TabBar>
```

```
await Shell.Current.GoToAsync($"//MainTabBar/{nameof(WelcomePage)}");
```